# Angular JSON-RPC: processing error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, json-rpc

I am trying to improve an AngularJS service for invoking remote JSON-RPC services. In accordance with the JSON-RPC specification, when an exception occurs at the server side, the response should include an error object with the description of the same:

```
response = {
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    result: null,
    error: "Description of the error",
    id: 1,
}
```

... where "id" is the identifier of the request original sent to the server.

The Angular component that I am trying to improve (https://github.com/ajsd/angular-jsonrpc) processes the responses from the server using $http transformers. I modified the original transformer, so that the new one looks like this:

```
transforms.push(function(data) {
    //Original code: return data.id === id ? data.result || data.error : null;
    if (data.error !== null) {
        throw data.error;
    }
    if (data.id !== id) {
        throw '[jsonrpc] Wrong response ID, id = ' + data.id;
    }
    return data.result;
});
```

As you can see, I throw an exception with the description of the error; which is a really poor solution since this service is based on $http promises and, therefore, the invoker of the service will find it difficult to catch the exception.

How can I invoke from within the $http transformer the "error" promise that the user originally sets while invoking the $http service?

```
$http.get(url).then(success(data) {...}, error(data) {...}};
```

Is this a correct approach or should I better base my modification on interceptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you left the code as you had it originally, you can define a service which uses the jsonrpc module:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    service('jsonrpcservice', function(jsonrpc) {
        var service = jsonrpc.newService('svc');
        this.get = service.createMethod('getData');

});
```

..in your controller somewhere:

```
jsonrpcservice.get({params}).success(function(result){}).error(function(err){});
```

you can handle the error in the .error() returned by $http